# PHP if (isset) JavaScript equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, dom-events

I have a problem here, I want to create conditions like if (isset) in PHP, but after ajax response
the response received here is like this if it is empty:

```
(2) [Array(0), Array(0)]
0: []
1: []
length: 2
```

and like this if there is data:

```
0: {description_content: "mnadmnsa",  course_content1: "madmna", course_content2: "mmnsadm", course_content3: "msadn", …}
1: {course_content1: "madmna", course_content2: "mmnsadm", course_content3: "msadn", course_content4: "msandm"}
    length: 2
```

I have tried with the empty method but an error:

> empty is not defined

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
              type : "get",
              url : url,
              success:function(data){
                if (empty (data[0]) !=null) {
                   console.log('has data');
                }else{
                  console.log('data');
                }
              }
```

Comment: To check if an array has values, use the length property. So `if(data[0].length) { /*has data*/ }`

Comment: if(data[0].length){
                   console.log('has data');
                }else{
                  console.log('no data');
                }
i try that but, i also no data

Comment: There's nothing even near similar to PHP's `isset` in JavaScript. Depending on the data type and what you're considering as "empty" you need different checking methods. If it's possible, that you're trying to check an undeclared variable, you'd even need a `try .. catch` structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `empty()` function, as that is invalid JS. With that said, here is you adjusted code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: url,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data[0] != null) {
            console.log('has data');
        } else {
            console.log('does not have data');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem still occurs, anything evaluated to falsy won't pass the check, including zero.